# axios REST call with JWT

Tags: javascript, rest, axios

I am running a local REST-API. When I test it with Postman I get the following results:

1. get JWT with same params and URL shown in the code below
2. use that obtained JWT in a request to get data with the same params and
   'X-authorization' header as shown in the code below.

When I do the same with axios I get a permission error:

```
    axios
      .request({
        method: "get",
        baseURL: "http://localhost/api/",
        params: {
          action: "login",
          username: "user",
          password: "pass"
        }
      })
      .then(function(res) {
        const token = res.data.JWT; //token is correct
        axios
          .get(
            "http://localhost/api/index.php?action=list&object=media",
            {
              headers: {
                "X-Authorization": "Bearer " + token
              }
            }
          )
          .then(function(res) {
            console.log(res);
          });
      });
```

The problem: The second request fails and returns a permission error.

Screenshot1: Error in console
[image]

Screenshot2: Succes in Postman
[image]

Screenshot3: Request-headers
[image]

Comment: Can you copy/paste the error?

Comment: "returns a permission error" — You need to quote error messages, not describe them in vague terms.

Comment: What request are you making with Postman? What encoding are you using for the data?

Comment: try to change "X-Authorization" to "Authorization". Bearer authorization doesnt work with headers "X-..."

Comment: @KirillMatrosov it works perfectly in Postman. Just tested Authorization without success...

Comment: @Quentin thx for the tip: updated the question

Comment: @CodeDraken thx for the tip: updated the question

Comment: @Verhulstd please add one more screenshot: Request headers from Network in devtools

Comment: @KirillMatrosov updated it with the request headers. Thank you 4 your help!

Comment: @Verhulstd I consider it is about rights and server's config, not about js/axios. What do you have in .htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was a setting on the rest server. There was a minimum delay between getting JWT and data request.